# suggestions how to keep "calculated" a lot of "dependent" parameters

Tags: algorithm

I have several indicators which need to be "always up to date". I.e. when anything is changed I need to recalculate "dependent". I have several levels where each next level should be calculated only when previous level is calculated. Let me explain by this shining picture:

[image: Design]

At some point Assume that Franc changed. Then we should:

1. calc Franc / Dinar
2. calc Franc / Dinar / Peso

Or, if Peso, Franc and Dinar are changed all at once then we should:

1. calc Franc / Dinar
2. calc Franc / Dinar / Peso
3. calc Peso + Euro / (Euro + Usd)

So whenever anything at the `Level 0` is chagned we should recalculate all other levels. But

- we should calculate only required items. If Euro changed we do not need to recalculate Franc / Dinar
- we should not calculate anything more than once. if Euro and Usd are changed at once we should calculate Euro + Usd only once (not twice).

The most straightforward solution would be:

- store each level in array
- for each item in array track "listeners" from next levels (could be difficulty because for example Peso has listeners from different levels - Franc / Dinar / Peso from Level2 and Peso + Euro / (Euro + Usd) from Level 3, so two-dimmension array is required..)
- if item is recalculated then mark all it listeners to be recalculated too
- go from Level 0 to last level and recalculate items that marked to be recalculated (initially updated items are market to be recalculated, for example Peso).

I guess that my problem is kind of well-known and probably you can suggest me general well-known solution. I don't want to reinvent the wheel :) Thanks!

Comment: If all items already have levels then solution is simple, but do they have levels?

Comment: yes, they have levels. it's guaranteed that everything at right level. this is pre-configured by human :)

Comment: but "levels" is inventeed by me. i can use another structure. probably it's better to use single dimension array for example instead of two-dimension array. this is what my question about I think...

Comment: Dataflow programming does all this automatically. Take a look at the pedestal framework for Clojure for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think the level-based approach is decent, on the assumption that listeners are always on a lower level.

### The idea:

Have a 2D array containing your actual data, the first index is the level, the second is the position on the level. Let each element have a `willBeRecalculated` flag.

Have a `toBeRecalculated` list for each level (so an array of lists).

For each element, have a list of elements (the listeners) containing 2 integers - one for level and one for index.

For each element to be modified, add the element to `toBeRecalculated` on the appropriate level and set `willBeRecalculated` to true.

Then go through `toBeRecalculated` from the first to the last level, recalculating each element, setting its `willBeRecalculated` to false and, for each listener, looking up the applicable element, if `willBeRecalculated` is true, do nothing, otherwise, set `willBeRecalculated` to true and add it to `toBeRecalculated` on its (the listener's) level.

This approach doesn't go through all the data to check what needs to be modified / has been modified, it only checks applicable elements, and there are no repeated calculations.

### Example:

**For this:**

[image]

(For my abbreviations I simply took the first letter of each word. I'm using 0-indexed arrays)

**Actual data:**

```
[[E, U, P, F, D],
 [E+U, F/D],
 [E/E+D, F/D/P],
 [P+E/E+U]
]
```

**Listeners:**

```
E:[(1,0), (2,0)] // E+U and E/E+U
U:[(1,0)] // E+U
P:[(2,1), (3,0)]
F:[(1,1)]
D:[(1,1)]
E+U:[(2,0)]
F/D:[(2,1)]
E/E+U:[(3,0)]
```

**Modifying `E` and `U`:**

Add `E` and `U` to `toBeRecalculated[0]` and set `willBeRecalculated` to true for both.

Go through `toBeRecalculated[0]`.

When modifying `E`, set `willBeRecalculated` to false for it and set `E+U`'s `willBeRecalculated` to true and add it to `toBeRecalculated[1]` and set `E/E+U`'s `willBeRecalculated` to true and add it to `toBeRecalculated[2]`.

When modifying `U`, set `willBeRecalculated` to false for it and we check `E+U`'s `willBeRecalculated` and see it's true so do nothing.

Then go through `toBeRecalculated[1]`. When modifying `E+U`, set `willBeRecalculated` to false for it and check `E/E+U`'s `willBeRecalculated` and see it's true so do nothing.

### Note:

It might be better to have the listeners be pointers to the elements instead of a level and an index variable.

Comment: this is "straightforward" solution. i will use it if i will not be able to find something better.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is very similar to the straightforward solution, except that in the "Go from level 0 to last level ..." step, it doesn't need to go through **all** of the nodes to check which need to be recalculated, as it keeps a separate list of ones needing recalculation for this. And it gives an alternative solution for dealing with tracking listeners on multiple levels. And it makes the structures and process a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you say you are dealing with levels, some sort of tree data structure comes to mind..

But for your problem, I think it would work to model some sort of directed acyclic graph.

Your graph might look something like this (all directions are downward)..

```
                             root 
                   /     /     |     \     \
                 E      U      P     F      D
                 \     /
                  \   /
              (Euro + Usd)
```

If you traverse this like you would a tree data structure, you will update each conversion rate exactly once for each update to the currency.

Comment: I don't think it is a `tree` shape, because there is one more `root` (see the picture in problem statement).

Comment: @AnnieKim A tree can still be used effectively. You can always just make a root that has no value.. Then all Level 0 entries will just be children of the root node. See edit.

Comment: But how do you deal with `Franc / Dinar / Peso`, it has two parents not one like a `tree`.

Comment: @dukeling I do not know how his dependancies work, just conjecture

Comment: This is actually a DAG, not a tree. But it doesn't really matter, this node-based structure would work really well (as the traversal is guaranteed to terminate at one point).

Comment: @Joel The question makes me think of exchange rate - There is Dinar and Franc and then there's a conversion rate between the two. The values of Dinar and Franc aren't dependent on each other, but the conversion rate is dependent on both the values.

Comment: @Dukeling See Edit.  I still think this still works as long as updates are atomic.

Comment: As it stands (without any optimization), this could do a lot more work than required - when multiple values on which the same value is dependent change (multiple parents of the same node change), that value will be calculated for each change instead of just at the end.

Comment: @Joel I can understand most of your idea, but I still think your solution or explanation is still too rough..And you didn't say how to avoid multiple update of one node.

Comment: Well, it meets the requriement of updating all dependancies based on a given change.  For his purposes, it is efficient enough.  I did not fully understand the structure he was working with prior to this design.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing can easily be accomplished in a [reactive programming language.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)

The QML of Qt also provides a property binding mechanism that accomplishes this for a UI.

Looking at the implementations of Qt property bindings and other reactive languages may give you some implementation ideas.

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) page identifies libraries for reactive programming in Javascript, .NET, Python, Java, C++, and many other languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use polymorphism here.
Have a list of Currencies, each of which holds a vector with pointers (to the base class) of all depedant elements.

The base class forces them to include a function `update()` which is called everytime the current currency is updated.

The depedant elements in turn have pointers for each currency they depend on and use these to update themselves in their `update()` implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
class c_node_combi_base;
class currency
{
  std::vector<c_node_combi_base*> m_dependant;
  double m_val;
public:
  double value (void) const { return m_val; }
  void reg (c_node_combi_base * p) { m_dependant.push_back(p); }
  void update (double val);
};
class c_node_combi_base
{
  std::vector<currency*> currencies;
public:
  virtual void update (void) = 0;
};

template<size_t N, typename OP> // templated to differentiate types of nodes
class currency_node : public c_node_combi_base 
{ 
};

struct divide_d 
{
  double operator() (const double x, const double y) const {return x/y;}
};

template<typename OPT> // node type 2
class currency_node<2u, OPT> 
  : public c_node_combi_base
{
  currency *A, *B;
  OPT _op;
  double m_val;
public:
  currency_node (currency * a, currency * b)
    : A(a), B(b), _op(), m_val(_op(A->value(), B->value())) 
  {
    A->reg(this);
    B->reg(this);
  }
  void update (void) 
  { 
    m_val = _op(A->value(), B->value());
  }

  double value (void) { return m_val; }

};

void currency::update (double value) 
{
  m_val = value; 
  for (size_t i=0; i<m_dependant.size(); ++i)
  {
    m_dependant[i]->update();
  }
}
```

This enables:

```
int main (void)
{
  currency franc, dinar;
  franc.update(9.9);
  dinar.update(3.3);
  currency_node<2, divide_d> franc_dinar(&franc, &dinar);
  std::cout << franc_dinar.value() << std::endl;
  dinar.update(1.1); // updates franc_dinar automatically
  std::cout << franc_dinar.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Printing:

> 3
>   9

---

Perhaps you can have a `std::vector<std::weak_ptr>` of your currencies while each node holds a `std::shared_ptr` for each currency so the currencies may not got out of scope/be destroyed unless there are no more nodes refering to them